# $y'''+4y'=3x-1$ find the particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The characteristic polynomial: $r^3+4r=0 \to r(r^2+4) \to r=-2,0,2$

There are no repeats that have to be taken into account for the particular solution

Setting up the "trial"

$$y_p' = Ax+B$$

$$y_p'' = A$$

$$y_p''' = 0$$

I then got:

$0 + 4A = 3x - 1$

$$A = -\frac{1}{4}$$

The final answer is $y_p = -\frac{1}{4}x - 1$

However the answer is $$\frac{1}{8}(3x^2-2x)$$

Comment: How do you get $0+4A=3x-1$? Plugging in your derivatives gives $$0+4(Ax+B)=3x-1$$And your solutions to the characteristic polynomial aren't right. $r^2+4$ does not have real roots.

Comment: okay I see. There is repated roots and I multiply $y_p$ by x?

Comment: It's $r= \pm 2i$ not $r= \pm 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your derivatives are correct, but somehow they were substituted incorrectly. The resulting equation should've been $y'''+4y'=0+4(Ax+B)=3x-1$, which yields $A=\frac34$ and $B=-\frac14$, hence

$$y_p'=\frac34x-\frac14\implies y_p=\frac38x^2-\frac14x=\frac{3x^2-2x}8$$

as desired. Note that the $+C$ from integrating is the homogeneous solution given by $r=0$, which is why it does not suffice to substitute $y_p=Ax+B$ but rather $y_p=x(Ax+B)=Ax^2+Bx$ or $y_p'=Ax+B$. Hence $r=0$ is in a sense a repeat for the particular solution. This may be clearer if you tried to annihilate the RHS by differentiating twice, giving

$$y^{(\mathrm v)}+4y'''=0\implies r^5+4r^3=r^3(r^2+4)=0$$

where we see the repeated root $r=0$ come in.

Also note that the two other roots should have been $r=\pm2i$, leading to the $C_1\cos(2x)$ and $C_2\sin(2x)$ terms, with the full solutions being

$$y=\frac{3x^2-2x}8+C_0+C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

I would use a solution for $y$ itself instead of $y'$.  Note carefully:  there is no repeat in the indicial equation, there *is* a repeat because the constant term you put into your particular solution is actually part of the homogeneous solution.

Therefore you can't use the constant term, and you must compensate for that by putting in an extra power of $x$:

$y=Ax+B$ wrong, can't use the homogeneous solution term $B$

$y=Ax$ would be right if the right side were constant but not if the right side also has a term proportional to $x$

$y=Ax^2+Bx$ right, now it will work.

By the way, the roots if the indicial equation are not $0,\pm 2$.  They are $0, \pm 2i$, there are complex roots meaning some of your "exponential" solutions of the homogeneous equation become trigonometric ones.

Comment: It seems they had $y_p'=Ax+B$ though, not $y_p=Ax+B$.

Comment: could claify on the constant term in the homogenous solution

Comment: my complimentary is $y_c = C_1 cos(2x)+C_2sin(2x)$

Comment: @BlackKnightRider You have 3 roots to the characteristic equation. There are 3 corresponding terms to the homogeneous solution, not 2.

Comment: @blacknightrider the complementary solution also has $C_3$ from the zero indicial root.  Hence the issue identified in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following equation is given:
$$y'''+4y'=3x-1\tag{$\ast$}$$
Setting $u=y'$, then
$$u''+4u=3x-1\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$
The homogeneous equation $u''+4u=0$ is solved by $u(x)=a \cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$, with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Now try for the particular solution $u_p=Ax+B$ for the differential equation $(\ast\ast)$, and not $(\ast)$, which is
$$4(Ax+B)=3x-1$$
This is solved by $A=\frac{3}{4}$ and $B=-\frac{1}{4}$, so $u_p=\frac{3}{4}x-\frac{1}{4}$, but $u_p=y_p'$. Integrate $u_p$ to get 
$$y_p(x)=\frac{3}{8}x^2-\frac{1}{4}x+C$$